# Exporting Calculated Fields in Dynamics CRM Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm

We export a solution with all of our customizations from CRM and unpack it into individual files (using [SolutionPackager.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx)) to store in source control. This has been working great until we added some calculated fields.

When repacking using SolutionPackager.exe and importing we get an error that a FormulaDefinition file is missing. Sure enough, there is no `Formulas` folder anywhere in our source control.

If I open the zip file of the solution we exported, I see the Formulas folder, but unpacking that solution mysteriously makes the Formulas disappear. I have not found anything helpful about this, has anyone run in to this problem before?

Comment: Did you attempt to contact MS team ?